# É possível mover módulos do NodeJS para ser utilizados 'offline'?

Tags: node.js, grunt

Utilizo o `GruntJS` para projetos pessoais, gostaria de utilizar os benefícios desta ferramenta no trabalho, porém é limitado o uso da rede e não consigo instalar via prompt.

Tentei copiar o diretório `node_modules` mas não funciona, existe alguma forma de utilizar os módulos sem ter que baixa-los?

Comment: Pode citar quais módulos está usando e quais são os sistemas operacionais do computador do sue trabalho e o da sua casa? Desconfio que algum módulo seu seja compilado e sejam OSs diferentes, ou então você está fazendo algo errado

Comment: SO é o mesmo, Windows 7, mas por exemplo quando executo `grunt test` no prompt é informado que `grunt não existe ou n é um comando interno..`

Comment: vc deu npm install -g grunt-cli?

Comment: se eu rodar esse comando vai ser baixado da rede, e meu acesso a rede é limitado, retornando um erro de proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lendo os comentários, entendi outra coisa, que o usuário que instalar pacotes de node de forma offline e não utiliza-los no browser. Como a resposta anterior se demonstra útil a outros usuários não vou apaga-la.

Existe uma pasta do node (que no windows eu não sei onde fica, mas provavelmente fica onde você instalou o nodejs) onde ficam todos os node_modules que você instala com o comando `-g`, e uma pasta de binários `/bin` onde ele coloca os binários identificados no `package.json`, no windows o node adiciona no `PATH` (variável do sistema) essa pasta, então os executáveis são achados no console. Você pode fazer isso manualmente se não puder usar o `npm install`.

Já no linux eles normalmente ficam em: `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/` 
E os binários ele faz link simbólico em: `/usr/local/bin/`
Obs.: A pasta pode variar de distro pra distro.

[Como mudar o PATH do windows?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5024/como-mudar-o-path-nos-windows) (abri o tópico para lhe ajudar não poluindo sua pergunta e não colocando link externo)

A outra maneira é você executar os binários direto da pasta, também vão funcionar, vamos supor que você esteja na pasta do seu projeto e queira executar o `grunt`.

Pasta do seu projeto digite:

```
./node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt
```

Recomendo usar um [power-shell](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb978526.aspx) do windows pra trabalhar com NPM e não o emulador de prompt, pois você vai ter um ambiente mais elegante.

Por fim, não se esqueça que no local de onde você está copiando seu `./node_modules/` se foi instalado com -g não vai estar na pasta do projeto mas na pasta de instalação do nodejs, por tanto para utilizar e copiar todos do projeto instale todas dependências sem o `-g`, para poder usar caminho relativo como do exemplo.

Answer (score 2):

No browser ainda não existe uma forma de você utilizar a função `require` igual no node, então isso é muito importante pro entendimento desta questão. O pessoal da [CommonJS](http://www.commonjs.org/specs/) documentou algumas maneiras possiveis de trabalhar com modulos e pacotes no Javascript, a W3C está trabalhando com HTMLImports e um sistema de pacotes.

Diante dessas informações, você pode em alguns pacotes híbridos fazer link simbólico ou mover para uma pasta e carregar no seu browser usando o comando `<script>` desde que os arquivos estejam em um local acessível via web no seu servidor.

Existem 2 projetos interessantes que também podem lhe ajudar:

- **[Browsify](http://browserify.org/)** Permite que você carregue modulos de node no seu browser.
- **[Bower](http://bower.io/)** É um projeto muito promissor parecido com NPM, porém focado em pacotes para browsers, hoje também é muito usado pelo pessoal que usa o GruntJS, permite a instalação de pacotes do NPM, direto do github e até arquivos compactados.

E o [grunt-bower](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-bower) pode lhe ajudar pra trabalhar com ambos.

Comment: Já utilizo o `bower`, e não conhecia o `browsify`, obrigado pela resposta!

Answer (score 0):

Caso alguém tenha interesse, encontrei uma ótima e simples solução, é o [npmbox](https://github.com/arei/npmbox), que permite criar um pacote personalizado com todas as dependências.