# Como mudar o PATH nos Windows

Tags: windows, path

Gostaria de saber como posso mudar a variável `PATH` no ambiente Windows.

Sou usuário de linux mas sei que o windows também permite a utilização dessa variável de ambiente para encontrar seus executáveis.

Comment: Qual windows vc está usando?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Se você deseja alterar o `PATH` a partir da linha de comando/de dentro do seu programa invocando o shell, o comando é esse:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\minha\nova\pasta
```

O `set` serve para atribuir valores às variáveis de ambiente; no lado direito, o `%PATH%` **lê** o valor da variável `PATH` e a inclui na lista (de modo que ela vai ter os caminhos antigos **e** o caminho novo que você está adicionando). E as pastas no Windows são separadas por `;` (e não por `:` como no *NIX). Note que essa alteração é **temporária** (i.e. vale até você fechar o terminal/seu programa terminar de executar).

Se sua intenção é alterar essa variável **permanentemente** (para todos os usuários ou para um usuário específico), então procure pelas instruções para sua versão do Windows específica (as demais respostas também dão exemplos). Se você quiser fazer isso **programaticamente**, então pode ser necessário mexer nos registros do Windows. Veja [essa pergunta no SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8358265/520779) para mais detalhes. Uma resposta indica que é posível usar o comando [`setx`](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) em vez do `set` para tornar a alteração permanente, não posso confirmar isso pois nunca usei esse comando antes (tampouco sei a partir de que versão ele está disponível):

```
setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\minha\nova\pasta"

setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\minha\nova\pasta" /m
```

(o primeiro altera só pro usuário atual, o segundo para todos os usuários)

Comment: Escolhi a sua porque é a melhor resposta de fato e se aplica a todos as versões de windows disponíveis. Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: +1 porque citou alternativa para definir permanentemente via linha de comando. Eu até ia responder `set PATH=%PATH%;XPTO` mas com cmd padrão não tem como definir permanentemente como ocorre em Linux. Você contornou isso.

Answer (score 11):

Basicamente você tem que acessar as variáveis de ambiente, independente do Windows que você estiver usando.

Clique no botão direito no Computador e escolha Propriedades:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Escolha "Configurações Avançadas de Sistema"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vai abrir a seguinte janela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Clique em variáveis de ambiente, a seguinte janela abrirá:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Selecione Path e clique em editar

Comment: +1 resposta ilustrada muito bem formulada. Obrigado

Answer (score 6):

Siga estes passos (Windows 7):

> Botão `Iniciar`
>   Botão do lado direito do rato em `Computador`
>   No lado esquerdo do ecrâ que apareceu escolher `Definições avançadas do sistema`
>   Escolher `Variáveis de ambiente`

Comment: Bacana, não sabia que em Portugal chamavam o "mouse" de rato. Aqui no Brasil a gente chama de mouse mesmo.

Comment: +1 resposta rápida e assertiva.

Comment: @Maicon Carraro É a velha questão sobre o que deve ser ou não traduzido. Já tinha reparado que há termos que os brasileiros traduzem e os portugueses não e vice-versa.

Answer (score 5):

Pode ser alterado *modificando o registro do sistema* em todas versões do Windows, desta maneira fazendo-se **permanente** a alteração.

Navegue para `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment` e altere a variável `Path`.

Saiba [como alterar variáveis de registro no windows](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5037/como-alterar-registros-do-windows).

Answer (score 4):

**Windows 8**

```
    Arraste o ponteiro do Mouse até o canto inferior Direito da tela
    Clique no ícone Pesquisar e digite Painel de Controle
    Clique em -> Painel de Controle -> Sistema -> Avançado
    Clique em Variáveis de Ambiente, em Variáveis do Sistema, localize PATH e clique nele.
    Na janelas Editar, modifique PATH adicionando a localização da classe para o valor de PATH. Caso você não tenha o item PATH, será possível optar por adicionar uma nova variável e adicionar PATH como o nome e o local da classe como o valor.
    Feche a janela.
```

**Windows 7**

```
    Selecione Computador no menu Iniciar
    Escolha Propriedades do Sistema no menu de contexto
    Clique na guia Definições avançadas do sistema > Avançado
    Clique em Variáveis de Ambiente, em Variáveis do Sistema, localize PATH e clique nele.
    Na janelas Editar, modifique PATH adicionando a localização da classe para o valor de PATH. Caso você não tenha o item PATH, será possível optar por adicionar uma nova variável e adicionar PATH como o nome e o local da classe como o valor.
```

**Windows XP**

```
    Iniciar -> Painel de Controle -> Sistema -> Avançado
    Clique em Variáveis de Ambiente, em Variáveis do Sistema, localize PATH e clique nele.
    Na janelas Editar, modifique PATH adicionando a localização da classe para o valor de PATH. Caso você não tenha o item PATH, será possível optar por adicionar uma nova variável e adicionar PATH como o nome e o local da classe como o valor.
    Feche a janela.
```

**Windows Vista**

```
    Clique com o botão direito do mouse no ícone Meu computador
    Escolha Propriedades no menu de contexto
    Clique na guia Avançado (link Definições avançadas do sistema no Vista)
    Na janelas Editar, modifique PATH adicionando a localização da classe para o valor de PATH. Caso você não tenha o item PATH, será possível optar por adicionar uma nova variável e adicionar PATH como o nome e o local da classe como o valor.
```

Fonte: http://www.java.com/pt_BR/download/help/path.xml

Comment: +1 acabamos achando da mesma fonte essa resposta, site do Java.

Comment: Hehe, pois é...

Answer (score 2):

**Windows 8**

1. Arraste o ponteiro do Mouse (Rato) até o canto inferior Direito da tela
2. Clique no ícone Pesquisar e digite Painel de Controle
3. Clique em -> Painel de Controle -> Sistema -> Avançado
4. Clique em Variáveis de Ambiente, em Variáveis do Sistema, localize `PATH` e clique nele.
5. Na janelas Editar, modifique `PATH` adicionando a localização da classe para o valor de `PATH`. Caso você não tenha o item `PATH`, será possível optar por adicionar uma nova variável e adicionar `PATH` como o nome e o local da classe como o valor.
6. Feche a janela.

**Windows 7**

1. Selecione Computador no menu Iniciar
2. Relacionar o item
3. Escolha Propriedades do Sistema no menu de contexto
4. Clique na guia Definições avançadas do sistema > Avançado
5. Clique em Variáveis de Ambiente, em Variáveis do Sistema, localize `PATH` e clique nele.
6. Na janelas Editar, modifique PATH adicionando a localização da classe para o valor de `PATH`. Caso você não tenha o item `PATH`, será possível optar por adicionar uma nova variável e adicionar `PATH` como o nome e o local da classe como o valor.

**Windows XP**

1. Iniciar -> Painel de Controle -> Sistema -> Avançado
2. Clique em Variáveis de Ambiente, em Variáveis do Sistema, localize `PATH` e clique nele.
3. Na janelas Editar, modifique `PATH` adicionando a localização da classe para o valor de `PATH`. Caso você não tenha o item `PATH`, será possível optar por adicionar uma nova variável e adicionar `PATH` como o nome e o local da classe como o valor.
4. Feche a janela.

**Windows Vista**

1. Clique com o botão direito do mouse no ícone Meu computador
2. Escolha Propriedades no menu de contexto
3. Clique na guia Avançado (link Definições avançadas do sistema no Vista)
4. Na janelas Editar, modifique `PATH` adicionando a localização da classe para o valor de `PATH`. Caso você não tenha o item `PATH`, será possível optar por adicionar uma nova variável e adicionar `PATH` como o nome e o local da classe como o valor.