# Como alterar registros de Variáveis do Windows

Tags: windows

É fato de que programando para Windows, é possível armazenar variáveis locais, ou no ambiente, que no caso são salvas nos registros do windows.

Como se faz para **alterar as variáveis do registro do windows** utilizando a linha de comando, caso eu queira limpa-las manualmente para fazer testes com a minha aplicação sem estas variáveis já definidas?

Comment: Use o regedit.exe

Comment: Você diz via uma certa linguagem de programação ou diretamente via o sistema operacional? P.S.: Não entendi a sua edição: o que você quer dizer com "variáveis de ambiente do registro do windows"?

Comment: Via linha de comando seria o ideal, pois é mais fácil salvar o comando e repetir caso seja necessário, pois os testes são repetitivos. Realmente a edição ficou confusa, tava pesquisando em inglês li como enviroment e achei que tinha escrito besteira, mas tava certo mesmo antes da edição.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível utilizando o aplicativo nativo para windows chamado `reg.exe` via linha de comando. [Reg.exe documentação oficial](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/reg.mspx?mfr=true).

Exemplos de uso:

**Consultando:**

```
REG QUERY HKLM\Software\Microsoft\ResKit /v Version
// Mostra o valor do registro Version

REG QUERY HKLM\Software\Microsoft\ResKit\Nt\Setup /s
// Mostra todas sub-chaves do valor abaixo do registro Setup
```

**Adicionando**

```
REG ADD \\ABC\HKLM\Software\MyCo
// Adiciona uma chave HKLM\Software\MyCo na máquina remota ABC
```

**Apagando**

```
REG DELETE HKLM\Software\MyCo\MyApp\Timeout
// Apaga o registro Timeout e todas suas sub-chaves e valores

REG DELETE \\ZODIAC\HKLM\Software\MyCo /v MTU
// Apaga o valor de registro do MTU em MyCo na máquina ZODIAC
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode:

1. Utilizar o [`regedit.exe`](http://ss64.com/nt/regedit.html) para realizar as alterações
2. Caso queira acessar via código, você poderá utilizar a [API do Windows para este recurso](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx);
3. Alternativamente, [exportar o trecho desejado do registro do Windows para um arquivo, editá-lo](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310516), e aplicá-lo utilizando `regedit.exe /s [NomeArquivoComChavesDoRegistroEditadas].reg`;

---

**Complemento:**

Observando seu comentário, creio que a terceira alternativa seja a mais recomendada neste caso. Você pode fazer o seguinte:

1. Abra o `regedit.exe`, navegando para a chave do registro que você quer "limpar";
2. Exporte a chave do Registro desejada para um arquivo;
3. Edite o arquivo no notepad, excluindo as linhas de valores abaixo da chave. Além disso, inclua um "-" (sinal de menos) antes do nome da chave. Isso indicará que, ao aplicar o registro, a chave deverá ser excluída. Ficará assim:

   > Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
   >
   > [-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MinhaEmpresa\MeuProduto]
   >
   > <s>"Parametro1"="Valor1"</s>
   >
   > <s>"Parametro2"="Valor2"</s>
4. Aplique o registro (duplo-clique sobre o arquivo que você editou) sempre que desejar excluir a chave referida.

Comment: +1 bem bacana a resposta, mas achei uma maneira de faze-lo pela linha de comando que no meu caso como estou repetindo a tarefa várias vezes, facilita.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode montar um arquivo `.reg` também, e executar ele. Por exemplo:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\SeuREG\CHAVE]
"valor1"="conteudoValor1"
"valor2"="conteudoValor2"
```

Salva esse arquivo `teste.reg` e é só executar.