# Problemas com instalação do activator no windows 8

Tags: java, play-framework

Estou tendo problemas na instalação do typesafe-activator, ao abrir o activator.bat o prompt de comando do windows me retorna a seguinte mensagem: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Instalei o Java SE Development Kit 8 e o problema permanece.

Comment: Já adicionou a JDK ao PATH? Veja aqui: [Como mudar o PATH nos Windows](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5024/3117)

Comment: **Nota do moderador:** pergunta reaberta, ver http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1820

Answer (score 1):

Falta adicionar o java nas variáveis de ambiente :

> Meu Computador > Propriedades > Configurações avançadas do sistema >
>   Variáveis de Ambiente > Novo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Valor da variável você adiciona o caminho para sua JDK.