# Erros ao instalar Phonegap/Cordova - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, apache-cordova

```
Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.12.6 (x64) and npm.

C:\Users\Alexandre>npm install -g phonegap
npm **WARN** addRemoteGit Error: not found: git

npm **WARN** addRemoteGit     at F (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_mo
dules\which\which.js:72:28)

npm **WARN** addRemoteGit     at E (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_mo
dules\which\which.js:75:29)
npm **WARN** addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modul
es\which\which.js:83:16

npm **WARN** addRemoteGit     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)

npm **WARN** addRemoteGit  git+https://github.com/imhotep/plugman.git#0.5.7 resettin
g remote C:\Users\Alexandre\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\https-github-
com-imhotep-plugman-git-20c32d58 because of error: { [Error: not found: git] cod
e: 'ENOGIT' }

npm **WARN** addRemoteGit Error: not found: git

npm **WARN** addRemoteGit     at F (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_mo
dules\which\which.js:72:28)

npm **WARN** addRemoteGit     at E (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_mo
dules\which\which.js:75:29)

npm **WARN** addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modul
es\which\which.js:83:16

npm **WARN** addRemoteGit     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)

npm **WARN** addRemoteGit  git+https://github.com/filmaj/node-plist.git resetting re
mote C:\Users\Alexandre\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\https-github-com-
filmaj-node-plist-git-653fe22e because of error: { [Error: not found: git] code:
 'ENOGIT' }

npm **ERR!** git clone --template=C:\Users\Alexandre\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-
remotes\_templates --mirror https://github.com/filmaj/node-plist.git C:\Users\Al
exandre\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\https-github-com-filmaj-node-plis
t-git-653fe22e: undefined

npm **ERR!** git clone --template=C:\Users\Alexandre\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-
remotes\_templates --mirror https://github.com/filmaj/node-plist.git C:\Users\Al
exandre\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\https-github-com-filmaj-node-plis
t-git-653fe22e: undefined

npm **ERR!** git clone --template=C:\Users\Alexandre\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-
remotes\_templates --mirror https://github.com/imhotep/plugman.git C:\Users\Alex
andre\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\https-github-com-imhotep-plugman-gi
t-20c32d58: undefined

npm **ERR!** git clone --template=C:\Users\Alexandre\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-
remotes\_templates --mirror https://github.com/imhotep/plugman.git C:\Users\Alex
andre\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\https-github-com-imhotep-plugman-gi
t-20c32d58: undefined

npm **ERR!** Windows_NT 6.1.7601

npm **ERR!** argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "phonegap"

npm **ERR!** node v0.12.6

npm **ERR!** npm  v2.11.2

npm **ERR!** code ENOGIT

npm **ERR!** not found: git

npm **ERR!**

npm **ERR!** Failed using git.

npm **ERR!** This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.

npm **ERR!** Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.

npm **ERR!** Please include the following file with any support request:

npm **ERR!**     C:\Users\Alexandre\npm-debug.log
```

Enfim, ai em cima está o log, o que pode ser?

Comment: E você tem git instalado nessa máquina?

Comment: @BrunoCésar , possuo sim, instalei agora pouco tempo(faz 1 hora).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que, provavelmente, você não possui `git` instalado neste seu ambiente, já que `git` não é reconhecido com um comando, já que o log exibe a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
Error: not found: git
```

Se possuir instalado, inclua-o nas variáveis de ambiente/usuário.

Para solucionar isto, faça [download](https://git-scm.com/download/win) para o Windows e instale-o. Depois da instalação, ao executazr `echo %PATH%` no *prompt* de comando você deve observar na saída algo que contenha o caminho de instalação, algo assim:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\git\cmd
```

Se possuir isto na saída o é provável que comando `git` será reconhecido. Para ter certeza, digite `git --version` e deverá ser impresso a versão do `git`. Depois disto, o `npm` não mais apresentará este erro.

**EDIÇÃO**: incluindo informação da instalação quanto a alteração da variável de ambiente `PATH`

Ao instalar o `git`, por padrão a primeira opção é selecionando, conforme abaixo:

[image: Instalação de git no Windows]

Perceba que é dito que com esta opção a variável de ambiente `PATH` não será alterado, então você conseguirá utilizar apenas pelo *bash* e *GUI* instalados (ou seja, sendo acessados diretamente).

No entanto, como é o caso do *npm*, algumas aplicações/utilitários precisam que ele seja reconhecido como comando/aplicação, o que torna necessário que `PATH` seja atualizado. Para isto, você deve atualizar tal variável incluindo o diretório em que está `git.exe`.

Para informações de como alterar a variável `PATH`, veja em [Como mudar o PATH nos Windows](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5024/#5033)

Comment: Já havia feito a instalação, diretório está presente, mas na saída de `echo %PATH%` sai algo totalmente diferente..

`git --version`, `git` não é reconhecido como um comando..

Vou ir tentando aqui arrumar este problema.

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus então o git não está nas variáveis cara, confirme isto. O `echo %PATH%` vai imprimir muita coisa, o diretório do git é uma parte apenas.

Comment: Bom, eu revi aqui a instalação, e como deixei tudo por selecionado ao padrão do GIT, o GIT não era reconhecido no prompt de comandos(CMD), bom, apenas no BASH(eu nem sabia que era diferente do CMD), então coloquei no CMD a opção e rolou agora tudo OK até então! Se for possivel atualizar sua resposta com essa solução especifica(para complementar a sua que está mais completa!).

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus ok, vou incluir esta observação, mas o erro em si é que não está nas variáveis de ambiente, você pode até usar o git bash, mas não tem nada a ver com o que o prompt nativo reconhece

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus atualizada =)

Comment: Ficou perfeito para mim agora, com esse complemento entendi a diferença entre a primeira e segunda opção. Obrigadão e abraços.