# Example.java não e encontrado

Tags: java

gravei o Example.java na pasta Documents, usei o cmd no diretorio do javac,mas ao rodar o javac ele não encontra o Example.java

Comment: tem que executar na mesma pasta do arquivo .java. Clique com o botão direito segurando shift, e selecione **abrir uma janela de comando aqui**, assim, o prompt abrirá na mesma tela do arquivo.

Comment: E tem que adicionar o diretório do Java no Path do SO, se for do Windows pode ver aqui como que faz: [Como mudar o PATH nos Windows](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5024/3117)

Answer (score 1):

Você deve navegar até a pasta onde está o arquivo por exemplo em C:\Projeto:
`cd C:\Projeto`, então executar o comando: `javac Example.java`.