# Cmd builder parecido como o do visual studios

Tags: c#, winforms

Olá a todos eu gostaria de saber como posso fazer com que quando eu clico num botão o meu programa compilar ficheiros cs e mais para fazer um .exe e executar como o do visual studios se alguém sobre como posso fazer isso ou souber tutorials agradeceria se me indicasse.

Comment: " como o do visual studio" você esta usando qual  IDE ? você precisa adicionar mais detalhes do que deseja fazer seu enunciado está meio confuso .

Comment: eu quero fazer que quando eu clico num botão faça o mesmo que faz no visual studio quando clicas no start

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi , você deseja salvar os arquivos.cs e arquivo.exe do projeto em um diretório especifico ?

Comment: Não eu quero fazer o que o viual stuio faz quando clicas start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá pode executar o seguinte comando no prompt do sistema usando o CSharp Compiler (CSC.EXE):

```
csc File.cs
```

Para saber mais acesse: [Command-line Building With csc.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/78f4aasd.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: o cmd diz que não e reconhecido como um comando

Comment: Olha a preguiça....

No link que mandei tem este texto: 

O arquivo executável de csc.exe está localizado em geral em Microsoft.NET \ framework \ pasta deVersion no diretório do Windows. O local pode variar dependendo da configuração precisa de um computador específico. Se mais de uma versão do.NET Framework é instalado no computador, você encontrará várias versões desse arquivo. Para obter mais informações sobre como essas instalações, consulte Determining Which Version of the .NET Framework Is Installed.

Comment: eu to a ver o link eu simplesmente sou burro (não estou a brincar)

Comment: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 no meu caso!

Comment: Se preferir adicione a sua pasta no Path do Windows para que o arquivo seja localizado e executável em qualquer local: [http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5024/como-mudar-o-path-nos-windows]

Comment: só mais uma coisa quando eu executo fecha logo é suposto acontecer isso?

Comment: Abre o Command e dê um `CD \Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`
Aí digite CSC !

Se apenas clicar ele abrirá o command e fechará!

Comment: Obrigado pela sua ajuda se houver alguma maneira de o recompensar diga