# Problema com Git CLI no ionic

Tags: ionic3

Estou tentando realizar o aplicativo tutorial disponível no site do ionic https://ionicframework.com/docs//intro/installation/
mas encontro problemas sempre na hora de escolher o templete, cheguei instalar o Git no link indicado mas nada foi resolvido.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você instalou o git?! Depois de instalado, tentou fechar o CMD e abrir novamente? Verificou se o git está nas variáveis de ambiente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mensagem diz que o GIT CLI não encontra-se no seu *PATH*. Pois então, você precisa adicionar o Git no *PATH*. Veja abaixo como fazer isso:

1. Clique com botão direito em "Meu computador" e pressione "Propriedades"
2. Clique em "Configurações Avançadas do Sistema"
3. Clique em "Variáveis de Ambiente"

Logo depois, edite a variável *PATH* acrescentando o caminho do GIT, tanto o `.exe`, quanto o *CMD*. Veja abaixo o caminho padrão que você deve acrescentar:

```
;C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
```

Também é possível fazer isso através da linha de comando. Veja aqui nessa pergunta sobre [Como mudar o PATH nos Windows](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5024/como-mudar-o-path-nos-windows/5033#5033).

É importante verifica se a versão do Git é 32 bits ou 64 bits, porque dependendo da versão, muda o caminho no sistema operacional, que também deve ser verificado.

Comment: consegui corrigir esse problema as agora sempre dá isso aqui:                 git config --global user.email "you@example.com"

git config --global user.name "Your Name"

Comment: @Carolina__ se essa resposta resolveu seu problema, seria melhor você valida-la. Esse ai é outro problema. Esse erro dá porque você precisa configurar uma autenticação para seu GIT, inserindo seu nome e seu e-mail. Basta seguir essas instruções.