# Erro ao iniciar um projeto Ionic

Tags: ionic, apache-cordova, ionic3, ionic2, cordova-plugin

Estou com um problema para iniciar um projeto Ionic, já instalei o node.js v10.15.1, cordova 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1), ionic cli CLI 4.10.3 e eu só recebo o erro

> npm i
>   [ERROR] Command not found: npm.

Já realizei o processo pelo CMD e Git Bash.
PrecisO muito de ajuda neste caso.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Seu problema está com a instalação do NPM, que, ou não foi instalado, ou foi instalado de forma errada.

Se você instalou, não esqueça de reiniciar o computador após a instalação.

Caso isso não resolva, digite `node -v` no promp de comando e veja se ele encontra alguma versão. Se não encontrar, acesse o site do [NodeJs](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) para realizar a instalação.

Caso tenha encontrado, você pode tentar adicionar manualmente o local de instalação na variável de ambiente `PATH`. Para isso, siga os passos descritos nessa outra resposta do StackOverflow [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47524025/8741188) para editar a variável de ambiente `PATH`. E em seguida, adicione isso ao final do texto:

```
;C:\Program Files\nodejs\
```

> Apenas adicione ao final, não substitua todo o texto!

Comment: O NPM está instalado, versão 6.4.1 com node v10.15.1, já reiniciei o computador, agora quanto a configuração dessas variáveis de ambiente você pode me orientar melhor?

Comment: Siga esses passos descrito [nessa resposta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5030/122846), é a melhor forma na qual eu posso te mostrar como adicionar aquele valor nas variáveis de ambiente.